# JNLP app blocked by security settings only when port specified

Tags: java, security, port, jnlp

I have a JNLP app that runs successfully when it references our internal production server. When I attempt to run pointing to our internal test server or my local machine it gets blocked with the Java Security error. Other details and attempted resolutions:

- One difference between prod & non-prod is the port is specified in the URL.
- I edited the site exception list, with fully qualified and wildcard (/) paths, without success. (The production URL isn't listed).
- Java is configured for High security (the lowest setting) and there's no Deployment Ruleset for our site.
- I tried javaws -verbose but received no meaningful information
- I enabled Java tracing and logging, but there's only minimal messaging
- Turned on the Java console, but it doesn't display in the case of the failures
- App is signed with a current certificate
- filesize parameter in JNLP has been updated

I tried all the advice in this post without making any progress: [Java jnlp application blocked by Security settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20967995/java-jnlp-application-blocked-by-security-settings). Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by examining library JARs and found they had been signed with a different certificate. Unsigned them, signed with the current certificate and rebuilt/repackaged. Was able to view JAR contents in Netbeans and with zip utility embedded certs were different.